# Using Real Time Data (Origin Destination Delay) with Dash Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to stream traffic data onto a map through an open-data API and dash (although happy to use another tool).

https://vicroadsopendata-vicroadsmaps.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/bluetooth-travel-time-updates-every-2-minutes/data

The above data sets. I have already built a mapping tool with just individual markers and changing heatmap intensity.

I have been playing around with dash to try and achieve this - > the real time map is a bit more difficult it would appear.

Grabbing the data as below,

```
bt_tt = "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/b0c4b78ca7b7446dbcee455c42987b95_1.geojson"
responsett = requests.get(bt_tt)
dict_bt_tt=responsett.json()
df_bt_tt = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_bt_tt["features"])
df_bt_tt = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df_bt_tt['properties']])
```

I want to then take the origin, destination, and the site lat and lon,

```
bt_sites_url = "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/48fd4d7e1127453ea5f9bdc757ab00e7_0.geojson"
params = "properties"
response = requests.get(bt_sites_url, params)
dict_bt=response.json()


df_bt = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_bt["features"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df_bt['properties']])
bt_df = df1[['SITE_NAME','SITE_NO','LATITUDE','LONGITUDE']].set_index("SITE_NO")
bt_df
```

and then after having essentially wrangled out the majority of the data required - how the fuck do i create a line graph that updates with this real time api every 30 seconds?

Thinking - using intervals with this tutorial in mind, https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/blob/master/apps/dash-wind-streaming/app.py .

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What kind of lines do you want to make? Does this not suit you? https://plot.ly/python/lines-on-maps/

Comment: Yes, you would use the `interval` component for this. You'll need to set up a callback function with the `interval` as its `Input`, and the `dcc.Graph` component as the `Output`. If you have trouble with that, then you can update your post and we'll try to help out more.-